# Update only changed fields in Mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to update a subdocument using ExpressJS and Mongoose. But only the fields that are changed. but somehow it updates all necesary field but also the fields that don't need to be changed.

This is the Update function in ExpressJS:

```
postController.updateMessage = function(req, res, item) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var saveData = {
    title: req.body.title,
    text: req.body.text,
    title_double: req.body.title_double,
    text_double: req.body.text_double
  };
  item.findOneAndUpdate({'subitem.messages._id': id}, {$set:{'subitem.$.messages': saveData}}, {upsert: true, new: true},(error, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

And this is the Mongoose Model:

```
var submessages = mongoose.Schema({
  date: String,
  type: String,
  title: String,
  text: String,
  title_double: String,
  text_double: String
});

var subitems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  messages: [submessages]
});

var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem: [subitems]
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two nested array while your are check/condtions on one array

```
{$set:{'subitem.$.messages.$': saveData}}
```

something like that on your condition